# GoogleMaps or Cesium to render dynamical geometries on a Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, three.js

I'm currently really confused, and I do need an advice.

My current aim is to get a Satellite view of a random building, with the tipical RoadMap\3d effect of Google maps:

[image]

and being able to use three.js on it, rendering polys overlapping that map.

I've followed example from this git repo:

[ubilabs/google-maps-api-threejs-layer](https://github.com/ubilabs/google-maps-api-threejs-layer)

But I can include particles on a map...I can't put on it geometries like polygons, splines and such.

I don't know what to do know...maybe Cesium is the answer?

But Cesium doesn't have the same "3d" option on buildings...

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: for polygon, line and marker you can use google maps v3

Comment: the earth v3 can do polygons? can u post me some recent tuts?

Comment: google maps v3 not google heart .. (could be is possibile too) .. but i mentioned  google maps ..

Comment: anyways, earth api are deprecated, and google api will shutdown this year, is not a good choice i think.

Comment: I'm speaking about google maps and not google earth  .. google maps v3.. are in use and are the same that render  .. the maps you provided in your question .. then ..........

Comment: If I've understand u well, the only one method of maps api you're talking about is the CanvasLayer, which is the basical thing that was used to build the Git Project I've linked above. By the way very poorly documented, I don't know how to accomplish my task, still very confused.

Comment: No i'm talking about native polygon , polyline, marker . or native drwing tools of google maps v3   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools  and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

Comment: so lines and circles. what about 3d? I mean, If I would like to use libs like three.js?

Comment: You have this in your question "I can't put on it geometries like polygons, splines and such."

Comment: http://johndyer.name/drawing-3d-objects-and-building-on-google-maps/

Comment: Yes definetely right, I wasn't clear enough about it, but Dyer's link that you've provided is what I was searching for.
Pls answer with this link and I'll mark as solved.
Thanks ;)

Comment: I have posted the answer with the main concepts ... thank

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111335/discussion-between-mark-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For polygon, line and marker you can use google maps v3

You can see this link google developer link for a firts evaluation

i'm talking about native polygon , polyline, marker . or native drwing tools of google maps v3 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple

but more useful is this link  Dyer
http://johndyer.name/drawing-3d-objects-and-building-on-google-maps/

where with proper function you can build your 3d object

```
function drawExcrudedShape(map, coordinates, height, strokeColor, strokeOpacity, strokeWeight, fillColor, fillOpacity) {

var pairs = [],
    polygons = [];

// build line pairs for each wall
for (var i=0; i<coordinates.length; i++) {

    var point = coordinates[i],
        otherIndex = (i == coordinates.length-1) ? 0 : i+1,
        otherPoint = coordinates[otherIndex];

    pairs.push([point, otherPoint]);
}

// draw excrusions
for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {

    var first = pairs[i][0],
        second = pairs[i][1],
        wallCoordinates =  [
            new google.maps.LatLng(first[0],first[1]),
            new google.maps.LatLng(first[0]+height,first[1]),
            new google.maps.LatLng(second[0]+height,second[1]),
            new google.maps.LatLng(second[0],second[1])                                 
        ],
        polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: wallCoordinates,
            strokeColor: strokeColor,
            strokeOpacity: strokeOpacity, 
            strokeWeight: strokeWeight,
            fillColor: fillColor,
            fillOpacity: fillOpacity
            zIndex: zIndexBase+i
        });

    polygon.setMap(map);

    polygons.push(polygon);
}       

return polygons;
```

}

Comment: it seems that only works the "draw base" attempt. Drawing walls functions doesn't show anything on screen even if there's no errore in Google Console of my Chrome. I'll try to rearrange things, maybe I'll open a new post here for this new problem.